# Fuzzy match text inside elements to a time string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabella">
        <div class="rigaHead"></div>

                <div class="rigaEven">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                        <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2 half">
                        <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3">
                         <p class="what">YYY</p>
                        <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rigaOdd">
                  <div class="col1">
                        <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                        <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2 half">
                        <p class='when'>11:00 - 13:00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3">
                         <p class="what">ZZZ</p>
                        <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="search" onKeyUp="search()" />
```

I try to show only div when the text of tag when contains an hour(09:00)

```
function search() {
        var text = $('#search').val();
        $( "p").css( "text-decoration", "none" );
        $( ".rigaEven").hide();
        $( ".rigaOdd").hide();

        $( ".rigaEven:contains("+text+")" ).show();
        $( ".rigaOdd:contains("+text+")" ).show();

        $( "p:contains("+text+")" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
    }
```

But it doesn't work, the code `$( ".rigaEven:contains("+text+")" ).show();` only works if it contains the exact text, or if the text is 9:00 to 11:00 and my input is 9:00 not see anything?

Comment: Are you expecting some kind of fuzzy matching to work here? i.e. 09:00 would match 9:00?

Comment: Also, you have a string of questions which you never accept the answers on, you will get much better results here if you accept an answer which has helped you. You can do so retrospectively.

Answer (score 1):

try to use below function:

```
function search() {
        var text = $('#search').val();
        $( "p").css( "text-decoration", "none" );
        $( ".rigaEven").hide();
        $( ".rigaOdd").hide();

        $( ".rigaEven:contains("+text+")" ).show();
        $( ".rigaOdd:contains("+text+")" ).show();

        $( "p.when:contains("+text+")" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
    }
```

I just replace one line from your script:

From  `$( "p:contains("+text+")" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );`
To

```
$( "p.when:contains("+text+")" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9k6xyf74/)

Hope it helps you. Thanks

Comment: Works....thanks but If I wanted that the CSS was applied only to text that begins with 09,10 and so how could I do?
Example text = 9:00 - 10:00 and another text1 = 10:00 - 12:00 in the search and if I write 10:00 I wish only text1 could see .... you can like what?

Comment: ok you want search like between if you want put 10:00 in search box you want show only 10:00 - 12:00 and hide 9:00-10:00 right ?

Comment: or if any one search 10:15 ?

Comment: Only 9,10,11 o'clock

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of spare time so I had a quick look into how to solve this.

I used [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to parse valid time signatures out of the input field and the text contained within the specified elements on the page. A quick search revealed a [simple regex](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/) which did this for me.

Instead of using jQuery to do the DOM work I instead just used the [Document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) which is built in to the web. This allows me to get elements on the page and information contained within them, in this case the `innerText` and the `value`.

With the text of both the elements we are interested in and the input field obtained and parsed for strings which match a time signature using [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and then [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to further narrow the results to those containing a colon character `:` I passed the results into moment.js.

I used [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) because it just simplifies working with dates and times. This almost certainly could have been done without any libraries and moment is a pretty bloated one, but for time saving purposes I used it.

Moment essentially takes care of the fuzzy matching here, we can just allow moment to do the heavy lifting and then compare the "moments" which we are given.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xx1wqsh/4/) which is working with your original HTML.

This is the javascript I used to complete the task, not the prettiest but I used up all the time I was prepared to spend on this.

```
function search() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search').value;
  var matchedTimes = matchTimeSignatures(searchString);
  if (matchedTimes) {
    searchCachedElements(matchedTimes.shift());
  }
}

function matchTimeSignatures(text) {
  var results = text.match(/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/);
  if (results) {
    return parseMatches(results);
  }
}

function parseMatches(matchesArray) {
    var dateArray = [];
    matchesArray.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.indexOf(':') !== -1) {
        dateArray.push(new moment(item, 'h:mm'));
    }
  });
  return dateArray;
}

function searchCachedElements(timeToMatch) {
  var elements = getElements();
  Object.keys(elements).forEach(function(el) {
    var matches = matchTimeSignatures(elements[el].innerText);
    if (compareResults(matches, timeToMatch)) {
      elements[el].style.display = 'initial';
    }
  });
}

function compareResults(matches, timeToMatch) {
  var positiveMatch = false;
  matches.forEach(function(match) {
    if (match.toString() === timeToMatch.toString()) {
      positiveMatch = true;
    }
  });

  return positiveMatch;
}

function getElements() {
  return {
    rigaEvenElement: document.querySelector('.rigaEven'),
    rigaOddElement: document.querySelector('.rigaOdd')
  };
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', search);
```